# Can you grapple while using this item from Princes of the Apocalypse?

Tags: dnd-5e, magic-items, grapple

In *Princes of the Apocalypse* the following item exists:

> [**Claws of the Umber Hulk**](https://www.dndbeyond.com/magic-items/claws-of-the-umber-hulk):
>  [...] While wearing the claws, you can't manipulate objects or cast spells with somatic components.
>
>  - *Princes of the Apocalypse* (page 222) Magic Items

This item does not actually say it prevents you from grappling, but the [requirements to grapple](https://www.dndbeyond.com/sources/basic-rules/combat#Grappling) are as follows:

> [...] Using **at least one free hand,** you try to seize the target by making a grapple check instead of an attack roll [...]

Do you still have a free hand while wearing both of the items above (left hand and right hand)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## You can grapple

The rules only do what they say they do. In this case the gauntlets prevent you from manipulating objects, and casting spells with somatic components, that's all.

Grappling is not manipulating objects, grappling is not a spell with somatic components.

For clarification: objects are things like rocks, a tankard of ale, a sword, a scroll. Creatures are not objects.